# Delete some items from an array and shrink array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, resize, shrink

I have an array like this:
double[] **my_input_array** = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
and some known **positions** which represent where to remove items from the array.
For example if positions are 3 and 7 I would like to get a **my_output_array** = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 };

So I would like to have a function like this:

```
public double[] getShinkedArray(double[] my_input_array, int... positions){
    /* SOME CODE */
    return my_output_array;
}
```

I noticed this question [Delete item from array and shrink array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870188/delete-item-from-array-and-shrink-array) but these answers remove only one element at time from an array.

Comment: Removing multiple elements is basically the same except you do it multiple times or check an array of positions. What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't shrink an array, you need to create a new one with the new size. You could do something like:

```
public double[] getShinkedArray(final double[] my_input_array, final int... positions) {
    double[] outputArray = new double[my_input_array.length - positions.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < my_input_array.length; i++) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(positions, i) < 0) {
            outputArray[j++] = my_input_array[i];
        }
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```

Comment: +1 this assumes all the positions are in sorted order, present and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array, loop through the old one, for each step of the loop check if the loop index is present in `positions`. If it is, go to the next iteration of the loop. If it isn't, add the element at that index in the old array to the new array. Return the new array.