# removing element from array- java

Tags: java, arrays

I try to remove an element from java array and shift the array, update the total value and the count.
Here is the code segment that I wrote, it gives me wrong result, how can I fix it?

```
public void remove(int index)
{
    if(index > count-1 || index <0)
        System.out.println("Incorrect index.");
    else{
        if(index ==1){
            total -= numbers[index];
            numbers = new int [0];
            count--;
        }else{
            total -= numbers[index];
            for(int i=index; i < count; i++)
                numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
            count--;
        }

    } 
}
```

I test the code with this;

```
NumberList n10 = new NumberList(-5); 
n10.add(45); 
n10.remove(0);
System.out.println(n10); 
n10.add(12); 
n10.add(25); 
n10.add(20);
System.out.println(n10); 
n10.remove(1);
n10.remove(1);
n10.remove(0);
System.out.println(n10);
```

I get

```
Size of the array must be greater than 0. [Empty List] [12, 25, 20]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at NumberList.remove(NumberList.java:113)   
        at Prelab8.main(Prelab8.java:102)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete item from array and shrink array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870188/delete-item-from-array-and-shrink-array)

Comment: Do you mean `count == 1` in the `if`?

Comment: Please explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened. Include the stack trace for any errors. Ideally, extend your code example to be a fully working example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yes, I update it as count,but I still get errors.

Answer (score 1):

You will get arrayindexoutofbound in the for loop.
It should be

```
   for(int i=index; i < count-1; i++)
```

Final code sample:

```
public class Test {
static int count;
static int total;
static int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4};
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        count = numbers.length;
        for (int i : numbers) {
            total = total+i;
        }
        remove(3);

        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    public static void remove(int index)
    {
        if(index > count-1 || index <0)
            System.out.println("Incorrect index.");
        else{
            if(index ==1){
                total -= numbers[index];
                numbers = new int [0];
                count--;
            }else{
                total -= numbers[index];
                for(int i=index; i < count-1; i++)
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
                count--;
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I check your code but it still gives 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at NumberList.remove(NumberList.java:104)
 at Prelab8.main(Prelab8.java:102)

Comment: I dont have your NumberList.java or Prelab8.main classes so cannot comment on the error