# Deletion algorithm for array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

```
Deletion(int array[ ], int delete, int position)
```

So I have this method, see above, the first parameter is the name of the array, the second is the value I want deleted, and the third is the index of which it can be found. For example:

```
Deletion(list,50,4);
```

In this case, the array I chose is called list, the value I want deleted is 50, and the index of which the value is located is 4.

If we were to use `Deletion(list,50,4)`, this method is supposed to replace the 50 at the index of 4 with the element at the index of 5 and the element at index of 5 is replaced with the element at index of 6 and so on.

If this is the array list: 90 76 55 48 **50** 69 66 52 87 56 89 91 86 73 50 68 52 75 54 45

The output should be: 90 76 55 48 **69** 66 52 87 56 89 91 86 73 50 68 52 75 54 45 45

However,I can only get it to replace the 50 but not any of the other numbers.

This is the output I get: 90 76 55 48 **69** 69 66 52 87 56 89 91 86 73 50 68 52 75 54 45

The 50 is replaced with the 69 but everything else stays the same, I need the other elements to "shift" to the left.

Here is my code so far for the Deletion method:

```
for (int i=array.length-1; i<position; i ++)
  array[i] = array[ i+1];
array[position] = array[position+1]
```

The length of the list is 20, subtract 1, so `i = 19`. I know 19 is not less than 4 so it skips the for loop, but if I made it `i > position`, I get this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20

So this is where I'm stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine the value of `i` so that it is initialized as the the int value of position (so that your deletion/replacement process can start there).

```
for (int i = position; i < array.length - 2; i++)
{
    array[i] = array[i+1];
}
```

Your `i.max_value` should be `array.length-2` so that `i` will incrementally increase until the end of the array. It shouldn't be -1  since you are essentially deleting the last index of your array (as the value has nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better be using `System.arraycopy` instead on implementing your own algorithm for moving array elements. Like this:

```
System.arraycopy(array, position+1, array, position, array.length-position);
```

Also see this question: [Delete item from array and shrink array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870188/delete-item-from-array-and-shrink-array)