# Is there any way to copy an array to the same array with less number of elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 8 elements, and I need to remove the first element from it and copy it to the same array. I tried it using System.arraycopy(...) but the size of the array did not change.

```
int[] array = {90,78,67,56,45,34,32,31};
System.arraycopy(array, 1, array, 0, array.length-1);
```

what I need is, the array should consist 78,67,56,45,34,32,31 elements with the array size of 7

there is a way to do this by copying this to another array and assigning it to the first array

```
int arrayB = new int[array.length-1];
System.arraycopy(array, 1, arrayB, 0, array.length-1);
array = arrayB;
```

but this is not the way I want. I need it to be done without the help of another array.

Comment: arrays are **fixed length** in Java

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using arrays? I thing something like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) could be a better choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot change the size of an array in Java. Therefore, what you are trying to do is impossible.

---

FWIW: the most concise way to copy to a >>new<< array reducing its size by one (as per your example) is:

```
int[] arrayB = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayA, 1, arrayA.length);
```

And you can copy elements >>within<< an array using a loop, or using `System.arrayCopy`.  The `arraycopy` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) says:

> "If the `src` and `dest` arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos + length - 1` were first copied to a temporary array with `length` components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions `destPos` through `destPos + length - 1` of the destination array."

In other words, you don't need to do an explicit double copy.

Comment: So the method I mentioned is the only way to achieve this? (copying to another array and copy the second array to the first)

Comment: No it isn't.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting an element from Java array and then shrinking array size is not a possibility in Java as arrays are of fixed length. Folks use different data structures like ArrayList etc whenever requirement is as such.

Lots of options have been put in here but none are one line answers that you are looking for.

[delete-item-from-array-and-shrink-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870188/delete-item-from-array-and-shrink-array)
[how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java)

Of the options presented in above questions, I personally like the answer ,

> Using ArrayUtils.removeElement(Object[],Object) from
>   org.apache.commons.lang is by far the easiest way to do this.

Even in this case, the trick is to create a new array of new size and assign to same reference so original array is gone but yes, your application code is not required to create two arrays. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `Arraylist<>` in java

ArrayList  arraylistobject = new ArrayList();

use for delete 
arraylistobject.remove(Object);
it will automatic decrease  size of arraylist.size(); 
try this one for your problem it is best.

**why?**

**Array** is `static in size` that is fixed length data structure, One can not change the length after creating the Array object.
**ArrayList** is `dynamic in size` . Each ArrayList object  has instance variable capacity which indicates the size of the ArrayList. As elements are added to an ArrayList its capacity grows automatically.

for more [LINK](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/03/difference-between-array-and-arraylist-in-java-example.html)